# What is type of value recieved from Java Object in Android WebView?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a class, say A, in Java with few methods and some static variables.

I am building a WebView based application in Android. I have injected an instance of class A using addJavascriptInterface method. (The application is actually using Phonegap)

I have a Javascript function which performs RSA Encryption using public key K(n, e) passed to it.

```
encryptString(n, e);
```

The 'n' is returned by a method from class A, called like:

```
var keyn = window.A.load("publicKey");
```

This is where I have a problem. When I pass 'n' as string, and 'e' = "10001" as string too, the encryption works well. But, when I pass keyn recived from the method, it doesnt work.

```
encryptString("42342abcdefg2232", "10001"); // Works

encryptString(keyn, "10001"); // Doesn't work :(
```

I have logged keyn in logcat and it shows that value is recived correctly in the variable keyn.

What is the problem then?

PS: I have tried two different RSA encryption libraries and same problem with both. So, most probably it is not a problem in the encryption code I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was that I passed `keyn` as `new String(keyn)` and it worked. In the journey I found the differences between string literal and string object in Javascript. I suppose `WebView` basically returns an `Object` and we need to convert it to string object before passing it to the function.

Anyone who could elaborate it more is welcome.